# Freemarker escaping freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm using freemarker to generate a freemarker template. But I need some way to escape freemarker tags.

How would I escape a `<#list>` tag or a `${expression}` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using the [alternative syntax](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html) feature. I start the template with [#ftl] and use this syntax.

For the expressions I use the string literal feature: `${r"${expression}"}`

Comment: I use the same approach, which is a bit ugly but works. It gets really nasty if I use a variable of the outer template to define the property access of a variable of the generated template, which looks like this:

   ${r"${entity."}${propertyDescriptor.name}}

and ends like

  ${entity.creationDate}

given that the propertyDescriptor has the name "creationDate".

Answer (score 11):

You could also use: `${"$"}{expression}` if you find the {} nesting confusing.

Comment: The best of all alternatives suggested to date. Boggles my mind that there isn't a simpler way, such as `\$` - but there ain't. This is a good enough approximation of elegance...

Comment: unlike the other solution, this works even when there are quotes in the literal.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure FreeMarker to use `[=exp]` instead of `${exp}` (since 2.3.28), and `[#...]`/`[@...]` instead of `<#...>`|`<@...>` by setting both the `interpolation_syntax` and the `tag_syntax` configuration setting to `square_bracket` (in the Java API: `Configuration cfg; ... cfg.setInterpolationSyntax(Configuration.SQUARE_BRACKET_INTERPOLATION_SYNTAX)` and `cfg.setTagSyntax(Configuration.SQUARE_BRACKET_TAG_SYNTAX)`). Then the syntax doesn't clash with the default syntax.

There's one tricky case; if the template starts with `<#ftl>`, then it will switch the tag syntax back to `angle_bracket`. To counter that, just add a `[#ftl]` line before it.

See also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html

Answer (score 0):

In the case when you want to use non-raw strings so that you can escape double quotes, apostrophes, etc, you can do the following:

Imagine that you want to use the string ${Hello}-"My friend's friend" inside of a string. You cannot do that with raw strings. What I have used that works is:

```
${"\x0024{Hello}-\"My friend's friend\""}
```

I have not escaped the apostrophe since I used double quotes.