# How to output ${expression} in Freemarker without it being interpreted?

Tags: el, freemarker, jquery-templates

I'm trying to use Freemarker in conjunction with jQuery Templates.

Both frameworks use dollar sign/curly brackets to identify expressions for substitution (or as they're called in freemarker, "interpolations") , e.g. `${person.name}` .

So when I define a jQuery Template with expressions in that syntax, Freemarker tries to interpret them (and fails).

I've tried various combinations of escaping the `${` sequence to pass it through Freemarker to no avail - `\${`, `\$\{`, `$\{`, etc.

Inserting a freemarker comment in between the dollar and the curly (e.g. `$<#-- -->{expression}`) DOES work - but I'm looking for a more concise and elegant solution.

Is there a simpler way to get a Freemarker template to output the character sequence `${`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This should print ${person.name}:

```
${r"${person.name}"}
```

From the [freemarker docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_direct_string)

> A special kind of string literals is the raw string literals. In raw string literals, backslash and ${ have no special meaning, they are considered as plain characters. To indicate that a string literal is a raw string literal, you have to put an r directly before the opening quotation mark or apostrophe-quote

Answer (score 25):

For longer sections without FreeMarker markup, use `<#noparse>...</#noparse>`.

Starting with FreeMarker 2.3.28, configure FreeMarker to use square bracket syntax (`[=exp]`) instead of brace syntax (`${exp}`) by setting the `interpolation_syntax` configuration option to `square_bracket`.

Note that unlike the *tag syntax*, the *interpolation syntax* cannot be specified inside the template. Changing the interpolation syntax **requires calling** the Java API:

```java
Configuration cfg;
// ...
cfg.setInterpolationSyntax(SQUARE_BRACKET_INTERPOLATION_SYNTAX);
```

Then FreeMarker will consider `${exp}` to be static text.

> Do not confuse interpolation syntax with tag syntax, which also can have `square_bracket` value, but is independent of the interpolation syntax.

When using [FreeMarker-based file PreProcessor](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/) (FMPP), either configure the setting via `config.fmpp` or on the command-line, such as:

```sh
fmpp --verbose --interpolation-syntax squareBracket ...
```

This will call the appropriate Java API prior to processing the file.

See also:

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_alternativesyntax.html
- http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/settings.html#templateSyntax

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use #include with parse=false option. That is, put your jQuery Templates into the separate include page and use parse=false so that freemarker doesn't try and parse it.

This would be a good option when the templates are larger and contain double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

I had to spent some time to figure out the following scenarios to escape ${expression} -

- In Freemarker assignment:

> <#assign var = r"${expression}">

- In html attribute:

> `<a href="/user/${r"${expression}"}"> Some link </a>`

- In Freemarker concatenation:

> <#assign x = "something&"+r"${expression}"/>

Answer (score 3):

If `${` is your only problem, then you could use the alternate syntax in the jQuery Templates plugin like this:  `{{= person.name}}`

Maybe a little cleaner than escaping it.

Comment: Definitely cleaner.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `$$`?

I found from the Freemarker manual that `${r"${person.name}"}` will print out `${person.name}` without attempting to render it.

Perhaps you should also take a look at [Freemarker escaping freemarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641240/freemarker-escaping-freemarker)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the

```
${r"${item.id}"}
```

is the correct way as an example.

So I kinda full example will look like

```
<span><a href="/user/user-remove/${r"${item.id}"}"> Remove </a></span>
```

and the output will be :

```
<span><a href="/user/user-remove/${item.id}"> Remove </a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case when you want to use non-raw strings so that you can escape double quotes, apostrophes, etc, you can do the following:

Imagine that you want to use the string ${Hello}-"My friend's friend" inside of a string. You cannot do that with raw strings. What I have used that works is:

```
${"\x0024{Hello}-\"My friend's friend\""}
```

I have not escaped the apostrophe since I used double quotes.