# Can FreeMarker keep the original value if variable is not found?

Tags: freemarker

I am using freemarker 2.3.x. It is expected that not all variables are defined. And it is needed to be output as it is. For example, the template is

```
${a}
${b}
```

And the data model is `a=name`. Then the output is expected to be

```
name
${b}
```

By using `TemplateExceptionHandler.IGNORE_HANDLER`, the output will not contain `${b}`

For now I am adding a new entry `b=${b}` to data model. It works but it is kind of ugly workaround. And I need to know exactly how many undefined variable will there be which is a limitation.

Is there a setting or a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the least horrible way to solve this is on the data-model level. Only you shouldn't add "b=${b}" and such manually, instead, you should use a custom `TemplateHashModelEx` as the data-model (the "root"), which does that automatically. (That has the annoying side effect that Configuration-level shared variables, if you have any, will be hidden by the data-model root.)

Anyway, even in theory, it's quite impossible to solve correctly. Consider, what if you have `${a + b}` where `a` is present and `b` is missing. Well, it could be render as `${123 + b}` then, but you see things become involved. Ad then, what if you have `${a(b)}`, where `a` is present but not `b`, and then in a later iteration `a` is missing but `b` is present...

As of `TemplateExceptionHandler`-s, while you could re-print the failing expression when it was an `InvalidReferenceException`, as `out.write("${" + te.getBlamedExpressionString() + "}");`, it won't work for non trivial interpolations. Like for the `${a + b}` example, it would print `${b}`, silently removing the `a +`.

Comment: Not working in ${a + b} case is not a big issue. Thanks for your solution. re-print the failing expression would be the good-enough solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and found another way to skip variables you know are not in your data-model.

This template should print ${b}:

```
${a}
${r"${b}"}
```

result:

```
name
${b}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5207658/2618186

I would love to see how exactly your reprinting function looks like though. Might be nicer.