# Freemarker assigning escaped ${expression} to a variable

Tags: freemarker

I need to assign an escaped ${expression} to a variable in Freemarker

From the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207613/how-to-output-expression-in-freemarker-without-it-being-interpreted), it's clear that we can escape the $ sign in this way

```
${r"${expression}"}
```

This works perfectly outside Freemarker context, but doesnot working inside. I am trying to do

```
<#assign x = "${r"${expression}"}">
```

But getting the following error:

Template inclusion failed: 
You can't use "${" here as you are already in FreeMarker-expression-mode. Thus, instead of ${myExpression}, just write myExpression. (${...} is only needed where otherwise static text is expected, i.e, outside FreeMarker tags and ${...}-s.)

What is the way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to spent some time to figure out the following scenarios to escape ${expression} -

- In Freemarker assignment:

> <#assign var = r"${expression}">

- In html attribute:

> `<a href="/user/${r"${expression}"}"> Some link </a>`

- In Freemarker concatenation:

> <#assign x = "something&"+r"${expression}"/>

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<#assign x = r"${expression}">
```